# posts_per_page displays only 2 posts instead of 4 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a `wordpress/php` code as shown below in which I am trying to pull latest 4 channels at Line A in the code below.

```
function get_latest_channels( $instance_id = false ) {
    echo $instance_id;
    echo "<br>";
    if ( ! $instance_id ) {
        $query_args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'hello-channels',
                'ep_integrate'   => true,
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
    } else {
        $query_args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'hello-channels',
                'ep_integrate'   => true,
                'meta_key'       => 'instance_id',
                'meta_value'     => $instance_id,
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
    }
    $channels = new \WP_Query( $query_args );
    if ( $channels->have_posts() ) {
        $rtn = $channels->posts;
    }

    return $rtn;
}

$instance_id = 49;
$latest_channels = HELLO\Channels\get_latest_channels($instance_id);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($latest_channels); echo "</pre>". // Line A
```

The value of `$instance_id` is 49. On using 49 value, it should pull `4 latest channels`.

**Problem Statement:**

My code is working fine `dev/staging server` (meaning its pulling latest 4 channels at Line A) but in production server its pulling only 2 channels.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it pulls latest 4 channels in the production server.

If I comment this line `'posts_per_page' => 4,` in the else section of the `function get_latest_channels( $instance_id = false )` then `Line A` is pulling `30 posts` in dev server.

Comment: Areyou having the enough data?

Comment: enough data ? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: how many posts are available for your hello-channels  posts?
you need to debug your code line by line for getting exact error.

Comment: There are total 30 but we want to pull the top 4 posts only.

Comment: I wonder if there is a plugin on production that is changing the query? Just before `$rtn = $channels->posts` could you check what `$channels->query_vars` contains? Also, could you compare the 2 channels you get back with the 30 channels if you remove posts_per_page and let us know if the 2 are at the start or the end.

Comment: Have you checked this isn't an ElasticPress issue, if you comment out 'ep_integrate'   => true are the results the same?

Comment: You apply posts per page. At what page is the query at? May it be that you're at the last page?

Comment: The issue could be one of two: you don't have enough posts under "hello-channels" or not enough posts with instance_id = 49. Try to compare the two posts that are showing on production with other that aren't. you could find the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the wordpress WP_Query syntax for meta_key. if meta_value is numeric you should use "meta_value_num" instead of "meta_value".

official syntax page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Sorry, but no, this is wrong: "*if meta_value is numeric you should use "meta_value_num" instead of "meta_value"*". Instead, an example of correct `meta_value_num` usage is `new WP_Query( 'meta_key=instance_id&meta_value=49&orderby=meta_value_num' )`. And if the meta value is numeric, the correct arg to use is **`meta_type`** as in `new WP_Query( 'meta_key=instance_id&meta_value=49&meta_type=NUMERIC' )`.